# Referring to elements of a matrices list

Tags: r, list, for-loop, matrix

I've got a matrices list created as following:

```r
#create the database
vect_date <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
vect <- c(48,40,32,36,37,37,20,15,15,24,24,10,10,10)
vect <- as.data.frame(cbind(vect_date, vect))
vect <- vect[order(vect$vect_date),]
```

```r
#create levels depending on vect$vect value
vect$level <- 1
for(i in 2:length(vect$vect)){vect$level[i] <- ifelse(vect$vect[i]==vect$vect[i-1], vect$level[i- 1],vect$level[i-1]+1)}
```

```r
#create the list
monotone <- split(vect, f=vect$level)
```

Now, I would like to change `vect$vect` value of each of these levels/matrices depending on the `vect$vect` value of the subsequent matrix. I guess the issue consists of indexing elements and using for loops, but I don't know how to do that.
As an example, I would like to change the value of `vect$vect` depending on the fact that the subsequent is 10. In that case, the `vect$vect` value of that level should be multiplied by 100, obtaining:

```
vect <- c(48,40,37,36,37,37,20,15,15,2400,2400,10,10,10)
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use factor in R first to get your levels:

```
vect_date <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
vect <- c(48,40,32,36,37,37,20,15,15,24,24,10,10,10)
vect <- as.data.frame(cbind(vect_date, vect))
vect <- vect[order(vect$vect_date),]

vect$level = factor(vect$vect,levels=unique(vect$vect))
vect$level = as.numeric(vect$level)
```

So if we want to change the level that comes before vect that have values 10, we can do:

```
level_tochange = vect$level[vect$vect==10] - 1
level_tochange
[1] 8 8 8
```

This tells us we need to change rows with level == 8. Note I use %in% because in events where you have more than 2 levels with vect==10, this will still work:

```
rows_tochange = which(vect$level %in% level_tochange)
vect$vect[rows_tochange] = vect$vect[rows_tochange]*100
vect

   vect_date vect level
1          1   48     1
2          2   40     2
3          3   32     3
4          4   36     4
5          5   37     5
6          6   37     5
7          7   20     6
8          8   15     7
9          9   15     7
10        10 2400     8
11        11 2400     8
12        12   10     9
13        13   10     9
14        14   10     9
```